# React rendering multiple components despite using 'exact'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router

I have a React app with a conflict between two routes:

`<Route exact path="/app/participants/register" component={ParticipantRegistration}/>`

`<Route exact path="/app/participants/:participantID" component={ParticipantDetailed}/>`

The first Route, renders fine. However, due to the `/:participantID` wildcard in the path of the second Route - both the `ParticipantRegistration` and `ParticipantDetailed` components render - despite using the `exact` parameter.

How can I get React to render only the `ParticipantRegistration` component when the path is `/app/participants/register` and not render the `ParticipantDetailed` component underneath?

I would prefer not to have to modify the paths as the app has a few other conflicts like this and keeping track of all the different paths is difficult enough as it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `Switch` to render only the one route at a time.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/x/register" component={() => <p>x</p>} />
        <Route path="/x/:id" component={() => <p>y</p>} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

You can play with the code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/oq3w0lv5yy)

Comment: Thanks @Prithwee - this certainly works. Now my issue is that I am using `ProtectedRoutes` which require each ProtectedRoute to be wrapped in a `Switch`. If I wrap each `PR` in a `Switch`, and then wrap the two conflicting routes above in a `Switch` the `ParticipantDetailed` component simply doesn't render. I might post this as a new question, however if you have any suggestions on protecting routes (ie. make them accessible only if user is authenticated otherwise redirect to login), I would much appreciate your insight.

Comment: Can you provide your implementation of `ProtectedRoutes`?

Comment: I'm not sure how you're using `Switch` in your implementation of `ProtectedRoute`.
But here's an example https://gist.github.com/prithweedas/adb1be17a789ff747f8800be7fdbf273 how I do it. Here I'm using redux state to determine the auth state. you can use your own authentication logic.

Comment: Sorry, just left the office so haven’t got the code accessible. Though, your Gist looks identical to how I’ve been doing it (learnt from a TraversyMedia tutorial). Previously I’ve needed to put Switch around each PrivateRoute otherwise the routes wouldn’t load. However, a quick try before I left and it actually appears to work fine if I just put switch around both the conflicting routes as in your answer. It renders the single component and the routes still appear to work. I will have a more thorough test once I get home.